# Virtual functions and double inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours, but I couldn't find the solution. Code example:

```
class IColor { // color interface
public:
    virtual void print();
};

class Color : public IColor { // abstract color class

};

class RGB : public Color { // color implementation
public:
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "hi";
    }
};

int main() {
    IColor* col = new RGB();
    col->print();
    return 0;
}
```

However, the result of compilation are linker errors:

```
/home/snndAJ/ccnvQHgL.o:(.rodata._ZTI5Color[_ZTI5Color]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for IColor'
/home/snndAJ/ccnvQHgL.o:(.rodata._ZTV5Color[_ZTV5Color]+0x8): undefined reference to `IColor::print()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(Not)working online example: https://ideone.com/YikYwe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your base class to have a *pure* virtual member:

```
class IColor {
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};
```

As your code stands, you are declaring `IColor::print` but never defining it, which leads to the unresolved reference that your linker is complaining about. A pure-virtual function requires no definition, and indeed no definition makes sense in this case, since every leaf class must override this method.

In fact, you will most likely also need a virtual destructor:

```
virtual ~IColor() {}
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: A pure-virtual function may have a definition but is not required to.